# Implementing ADFS in application how to?

Tags: saml-2.0, adfs

I need to implement ADFS in one of my applications but I'm having troubles with how to go about that.

My personal situation is that the application (SP) is hosted on AWS (hosting only) and the IDP is a third party organisation which implements Active Directory.
I think I have the theory worked out, like:

-the browser tries to access the SP
-the SP sends an authentication request to the IDP
-the IDP authenticates the user (the user physically signs in)
-an authentication authorization token is sent from the IDP to the SP 
-the user can use the application

It has been decided that I will have to use SAML 2.0 as protocol, but now I'm struggling to find out exactly what to do and where to start from.

I know that, somehow, SAML 2.0 has to be enabled at the application level (the SP hosted on AWS), but how exactly?

I've read a few posts on the net and here on SO but there isn't really - not that I could find at least - any kind of good tutorial demonstrating how to do it.

In particular, on SO, I came across the Spring Security SAML Extension and since my application is a spring application I was thinking that it could be a good idea to start with that, but is that all? Does it handle sending and receiving tokens? As far as I know the authentication request token is emitted by the SP (as mentioned) and then read by the IDP STS, which then sends back an authentication token, but does it do it automagically or does it need to be somehow configured?

Answer (score 1):

You don't implement ADFS in the application. ADFS is a separate IDP.

What language is your SP written in?

"IDP is a third party organisation which implements Active Directory" Is this the ADFS instance or something else? In which case, where does ADFS fit in?

What you need is a SAML stack on the SP (this is where where Spring Security comes in).

Spring Security provides federation metadata. This describes SAML endpoints, certificates etc.

You then import this metadata file into ADFS as a SAML SP.

You then configure claims rules for the AD attributes you want to send to your SP.

That's basically it!

Comment: The SP is written in Java.I thought SAML 2.0 needs to be enabled at the SP level. About the IDP all I know is that they authenticate their users through AD. Anything else I need to find out? About the SAML stack I found [this one](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-saml/) (it seems to be only a matter of adding a dependency to your pom file).I will also look at [this](https://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) as you said (again it seems like just a matter of adding a dependency to the pom file.) So, is this federation metadata an xml file that Spring Security generates automatically?

Comment: Basically you don't care about the type of IDP. All you need is the metadata and you need to supply yours to them. Sorry, not a Spring guru. Also: http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-connectivity-toolkit.html